Как мне сделать синхронизацию list в Unity + Photon
У меня есть скрипт который спавнит игроков при заходе в комнату
public GameObject player;
public float minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
public Restart restart;
GameObject playerSpawn;
private void Start()
{
    SpawnPlayer();
}

public void SpawnPlayer()
{
    Vector2 randPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, minY), Random.Range(maxX, maxY));
    playerSpawn = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(player.name, randPos, Quaternion.identity);
            
}



[PunRPC]
void AddPlayer(GameObject playerAdd)
{
    restart.players.Add(player);        
}

void CallString()
{
    PhotonView photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    photonView.RPC("AddPlayer", RpcTarget.All, playerSpawn);
}

как видите я уже пытался реализовать синхронизацию, но у меня не получилось.
public List<GameObject> players = new List<GameObject>();
private void Update()
{
    if (players.Count == 0)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}

а это код рестартера. Сейчас он просто бесконечно перезапускает сцену. Помогите пожалуйста.

А без перезапускания сцены?

без перезапуска работает. Я убрал  PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel и заменил его на print. И сообщение выводится когда игроков нету на карте.

А нет не работает. Я добавил в код вывод количества элементов в списке и настоящие значение только у хоста, а у игрока ненастоящие т.е у игрока один элемент в списка, а у хоста два
